# Issues using INSERT INTO ON CONFLICT using WITH queries

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-10

I'm changing queries from an Oracle Database to PostgreSQL, and in this query I am getting this error:

```
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"
```

the query is:

```
WITH d as (
      SELECT ? AS summary, ? AS eventTime), ai as (select * from alarm)
ON (ai.fault_id=? AND ai.external_key=?)
INSERT INTO alarm AS ai(
     alarm_id,
     fault_id,
     external_key)
VALUES (nextval('seq_alrm_instnc_alrm_instnc_id'),?,?)
ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET
        (${buildUpdateAttributes(attributes)}
        ai.summary = d.summary,
        ai.system_last_update_time = default,
        ai.event_sequence_number =
          CASE
            WHEN (d.event_number > ai.event_number) THEN d.event_number
            ELSE ai.event_number
          END)
```

I am using JDBC to connect to the database and here is the call code

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = super.prepareStatement_(sql_query)) {
    PreparedStatementHelper psh = new PreparedStatementHelper(ps);
    psh.add(attribute1);
    ...
    ps.execute()
```

I have tried different aproaches and taken a long look at Postgres documentation and cannot find what is wrong and didn't find any answer to this specific situation

Comment: I don't understand what the CTE (`WITH d as ...`)  is supposed to do there. Why do you provide the value for the summary column in the `values` clause for the INSERT? And the `eventTime` is not used at all  in the subsequent statement. And the `select * from alarm` makes no sense whatsoever in that statement. And the alias `d` doesn't contain a column named `event_number` so the reference `d.event_number` is also invalid. And you can't put the whole SET part between parantheses

Comment: Try removing the ON part and put the conditions in a WHERE. See [reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do there, you have mixed so many syntax elements in the wrong way that it's really hard to understand.

The two CTEs (`WITH ...`) seem completely irrelevant. If you just want to provide some values and do an update if a UNIQUE key is violated, the basic syntax is:

```
insert into the_table (col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4)
values (1,2,3,4)
on conflict (col_1,col_2) do update 
  set col_3 = excluded.col_3,
      col_4 = excluded.col_4;
```

The special keyword `excluded` is used to reference the column value supplied in the `VALUES` clause of the row that caused the unique constraint to be violated.

Your CTE provides a parameter `eventTime` which is then never used further down. Assuming that should be the `event_number`, then maybe you looking for something like this:

```
INSERT INTO alarm 
  -- specify all columns for which you provide a value 
  (alarm_id, fault_id, external_key,summary, event_sequence_number, event_number)
VALUES 
  -- provide a value for each column
  (nextval('seq_alrm_instnc_alrm_instnc_id'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
  -- define the columns of the unique constraint you want to "catch"
ON CONFLICT (fault_id, external_key) 
DO UPDATE SET
   -- "excluded.summary" refers to the corresponding value from the VALUES clause
   summary = excluded.summary, 
   system_last_update_time = default,
   -- excluded.event_number refers to the corresponding value from the VALUES clause
   event_sequence_number = CASE
                             WHEN excluded.event_number > alarm.event_number THEN excluded.event_number
                             ELSE alarm.event_number
                           END
```

Comment: hey man, thanks. I do not really know the basic elements of PostGres or even Oracle so I was trying to use what I had in the Oracle Query to try and migrate. This is also not the real query, because that one had atleast more 20 fields so I tried to simplify. I will try what you said